# Silverlight project modified in Blend cannot be built in a different computer with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, expression-blend

I have installed Expression 4 and Visual Studio in my computer. A coworker is in charge of building and deploying. The thing is that he doesn't have Expression installed and now we have problems building the project in his computer.
Is there an add-in for visual studio to keep developers and designers working together without having to install Expression on every computer?

Comment: There is an Expression redistributable that other dev's/build machines would need to install.  I don't have a link handy or this would be an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They need to install the [Microsoft Expression Blend Software Development Kit (SDK) for Silverlight 4](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3062)